# invertibility of integral operators on the half line

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $Tu=\int_0^\infty u(x)k(x,y)dx$ be an integral operator with kernel $k$. Note that the domain of integration is the half line.   Is there a general theory for invertibility of the operator $I-T$, say on $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$, depending on properties of $k$?  Here $I$ is the identity operator.

Comment: Like [Hilbert-Schmidt Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) etc?

Comment: Hilbert-Schmidt operators is one option. But, I opened the topic for a more general discussion.

Comment: So you have  in mind cases which are more general than Hilbert-Schmidt operators?

Comment: If you did not want to receive answers about HS operators then you should have said so on the question before someone took the time to write an answer

Comment: The question already says "general theory" to allow all sorts of answers. Discussion involving HS operators is welcome too and indeed may be very useful.  I am only saying that the goal is to discuss this in a more general context, not only limited to HS operators.

Answer (score 1):

So, $T:L^2\left(\mathbb R_+ \right) \to L^2\left(\mathbb R_+ \right)$.
A natural setup in this case is [Hilbert-Schmidt Operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator), that is,
when
$$
\int_{\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_+}  k^2(x,y) dxdy <\infty
$$
In that case,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\|Tf \right\|_{L^2( \mathbb R_+)}^2&=& \int_{\mathbb R_+ } (Tf(x))^2 dx \\
&=&\int_{\mathbb R_+ } \left(\int_{\mathbb R_+ } k(x,y) f(y) dy \right)^2 dx \\
&\leq & \int_{\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_+}  k^2(x,y) dxdy \int_{\mathbb R_+ } f(y)^2 dy dx \leq \left\|k \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_+)}^2 \left\|f \right\|_{L^2( \mathbb R_+)}^2
\end{eqnarray*}
So $T$ is a bounded operator. It is also a compact operator. Thus, the invertibility of $I-T$ is "maybe, maybe not" in the following sense :
There exists a most finitely many linearly independent functions $f$ such that
$$
f = Tf.
$$
There are all sorts of cases when the existence of such eigenvalues can be excluded. The simplest one is when $$\left\|k \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R_+)}<1.$$
In that case,
$$
(I-T)^{-1} = \sum_{n\geq0} T^n,
$$
where $T^n$ means $T$ composed $n$ times with itself.